# Finding $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where A is a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Given the spectral decomposition $A = PDP^T$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, I can define the following:

$$
A^{\frac{1}{2}} = Q D^{\frac{1}{2}}Q^T
$$

Is the following also true: if $A = P D P^{-1}$ where $D$ is again diagonal of eigenvalues then:

$$
A^{\frac{1}{2}} = Q D^{\frac{1}{2}}Q^{-1}
$$

I tested it numerically and it is true - just not sure if these two equations are absolutely equivalent.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is the square root of A also equal to the second decomposition?

Comment: Square it and see.

Comment: I did - it works out the same

Comment: Your $Q$ should be $P$. Can the eigenvalues be complex?

Comment: Correct it; what you wrote is confusing.

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric it can be diagonaized with an orthonormal $Q$ and $Q^T = Q^{-1}$

Comment: @DougM I can also be diagonalised with $Q^T \ne Q^{-1}$ (as in the second case). That's what I'm asking. The first case, $A = PDP^T$ Q is orthonormal. In the second case Q is not orthonormal

Comment: @s5s Isn't there a uniqueness of decomposition theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any diagonalizable matrix has a square root (provided you deal with complex numbers). If $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $E^2=D$, then 
$$
(PEP^{-1})^2=PEP^{-1}PEP^{-1}=PEIEP^{-1}=PE^2P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}=A.
$$